# Как не потерять EXIF при съёмке из приложения и последующим изменение файла изображения?

Tags: android, android-camera, jpeg, exif

При съёмке с камеры в приложении через `Intent` в `OnActivityResult` получаю готовое изображение и изменяю его размер. При этом исходный файл после всех операций удаляется и на его место копируется новый с тем же именем.

Как я это делаю:

```
File source = new File(path);
File imageFile = new File(mediaStorageDir, fileName);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inMutable = true;
Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opt); 
result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, 1200, 1600, false);               
result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, os);
os.flush();
os.close();
if (source.delete()) {
   imageFile.renameTo(source);
}
```

В целом код рабочий, но в итоговом файле отсутствует EXIF. Как правильно отснять или изменить файл, чтобы сохранить EXIF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сохранить оригинальный Exif

```
ExifInterface originalExif = null;
try {
    originalExif = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

А затем восстановить его для нового файла

```
if (originalExif != null) {
  ExifInterface newExif = null;
  try {
      newExif = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
      newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, originalExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME));
      newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, originalExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION));
      newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL, originalExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_MODEL));
      newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH, originalExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_FLASH));
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
          newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SOFTWARE, originalExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_SOFTWARE));
          newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PIXEL_X_DIMENSION, originalExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PIXEL_X_DIMENSION));
          newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PIXEL_Y_DIMENSION, originalExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_PIXEL_Y_DIMENSION));
          newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LIGHT_SOURCE, originalExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_LIGHT_SOURCE));
      }
      newExif.saveAttributes();
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Возможно еще нелишним будет проверка наличия тэгов.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую. Если прокатит, отмечу ответ как принятый.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!